# Select row names in case rows are equal to 1

Tags: r, dataframe

I need to solve the following problem, but can't seem to figure it out... 
I need the row names of a data frame like the one below in case rows like OIL_BE_pet are equal to 1. Of course, the original data is bigger than these 2 columns and 4 rows. Each row will only have a maximum of one "1". I would love to have these row names in the order as they appear in the data frame.

```
                      OIL_BE_pet      OIL_BE_pet2
Terminal One                0              0
Terminal Two                1              0
Terminal Three              0              1
Terminal Four               0              0
```

The solution here would be "Terminal Two", "Terminal Three".

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `rownames(DF)[DF$OIL_BE_pet | DF$OIL_BE_pet2]`

Comment: Why would this work? As I said, there are much more columns/rows in the real data frame. Also: you are using a logical operator, while my data is numerical as seen in the example.

Comment: R automatically coerces numeric values to logical values if you do logical comparisons with them. It's not my fault if you don't provide a reproducible and representative example. Maybe, `rownames(DF)[rowSums(DF) > 0]` or `rownames(DF)[Reduce("|", DF)]`.

Comment: Of course it worked. I don't remember having ever seen @Roland give a wrong answer. The other suggestions he made in the comments work, too.

Comment: @RHertel Oh, I have given wrong answers. I've just fixed or deleted them when I realized they were wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

May I suggest [`rowSums()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/colSums.html):

```
rownames(df)[rowSums(df)>0];
## [1] "Terminal Two"   "Terminal Three"
```

---

**Data**

```
df <- data.frame(OIL_BE_pet=c(0L,1L,0L,0L),OIL_BE_pet2=c(0L,0L,1L,0L),row.names=c(
'Terminal One','Terminal Two','Terminal Three','Terminal Four'));
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `which` with `arr.ind=TRUE`

```
names(which(df!=0, arr.ind=TRUE)[,1])
#[1] "Terminal Two"   "Terminal Three"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code:

```
df[as.logical(apply(df,1,sum)),]
```

It works by summing row-wise and finding which rows have a non-zero sum, and then subsetting the data frame by those rows.

This gives the result:

```
> df[as.logical(apply(df,1,sum)),]
               OIL_BE_pet OIL_BE_pet2
Terminal Two            1           0
Terminal Three          0           1
```